# Tab Color Issue in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need some help with tabs on a page.

1) I have the following tabs on my page.

[image]

By default when the page loads none of the tab is highlighted. I want the Business System Functionality tab to be highlighted by default. How do i achieve this?

2) When I select a tab, the tab color and the border are of the same color.

[image]

But when I hover the mouse over any other tab, the color of the border changes to the `hover` color. I do not want this. I want the border color to change only when I click the tab. How do I achieve this?

[image]

**My code here** - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vbfq3bf/10/)

Comment: Show your `css` & `html`

Comment: @jonju - There is an fiddle link in the question!

Comment: Oops! my bad.. it was too small I couldn't see it

Comment: @Pugazh - though you're supposed to show the minimal code in your question, links can expire - future visitors might not be able see his example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

1. Make your `.tab1` as current/selected on page load. Add below code to your `$(document).ready()`.

   ```js
     $('.tab1').addClass('current');
     $('.tab-content').css("border-top", "5px solid #3399CC");
     $('#tab-1').addClass('current');
   ```
2. Remove the jQuery `.hover()` to remove the border styling.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/3vbfq3bf/13/).

---

**Sample Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Apply current on Page load */
  $('.tab1').addClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').css("border-top", "5px solid #3399CC");
  $('#tab-1').addClass('current');

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {

    var contentid = '#' + $(this).attr('datatab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(contentid).addClass('current').css("border-top", "5px solid " + $(this).css("background-color"));
  });

});
```

```css
.home-tab-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
img.home-duck {
  width: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 10px 0 0;
}
.home-heading {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: right;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif;
}
.home-subheading {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.home-subheading {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.tab-content1 {
  margin-left: 2.2em;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
}
.tab-content1-block {
  padding: 0 1em 1em .5em;
  min-width: 30%;
}
.tab-content1-block ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: -22px;
}
— css —
/* Hide the user navigation for community and anon on home. Shows it for pro members. */

.columbia-page-home .elm-header-user-nav {
  display: none;
}
.columbia-page-home.elm-user-pro-member.columbia-page-home .elm-header-user-nav {
  display: block;
}
/* Hide the user navigation for community and anon on home. */

.columbia-page-home .elm-header-home-nav {
  display: none;
}
/* Hides the user nav's global search on home. */

.columbia-page-home .elm-global-search {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* Sets the correct positioning of the footer based on user role for home only. */

.columbia-page-home .elm-footer {
  bottom: auto;
}
@media all and (min-width: 78.75em) {
  .elm-user-pro-member.columbia-page-home .elm-footer {
    bottom: 3.4em;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .elm-user-pro-member.columbia-page-home .elm-footer {
    bottom: auto;
  }
}
li.ui-state-active {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
— css —
/* Code for PageTabs template */

body .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  width: 225px;
  word-wrap: initial;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
— css —
/* Code for new tabs */

. body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6 float: left;
}
container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.tab1:hover {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab2:hover {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab3:hover {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab4:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab5:hover {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab6:hover {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab7:hover {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab8:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab9:hover {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab10:hover {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab11:hover {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab1.current {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab2.current {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab3.current {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab4.current {
  background: #336699;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab5.current {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab6.current {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab7.current {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab8.current {
  background: #336699;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab9.current {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab10.current {
  background: #12B58A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-link.tab11.current {
  background: #673ab7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
  border-top: 5px solid #3399CC;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tab-link {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link tab1" datatab="tab-1">'Business System Functionality'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab2" datatab="tab-2">'Product'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab3" datatab="tab-3">'Environment Administration'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab4" datatab="tab-4">'Training'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab5" datatab="tab-5">'Release Notes'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab6" datatab="tab-6">'Architecture'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab7" datatab="tab-7">'Testing'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab8" datatab="tab-8">'System Administration'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab9" datatab="tab-9">'Site Management'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab10" datatab="tab-10">'Staging'</li>
    <li class="tab-link tab11" datatab="tab-11">'Regulatory Compliance Board'</li>
  </ul>


  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Business System Functionality
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @PankajMorajkar - I have modified the code just for illustrative purpose. Please make necessary changes as required.

Comment: @Pugazh...I have some content in the tabs...when i use your jscript, on clicking the tabs the content within the tabs is not visible...check the fiddle...                  https://jsfiddle.net/3vbfq3bf/15/.....      can you help?

Comment: @PankajMorajkar - Here is the updated code - https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/3vbfq3bf/16/

Comment: @Pugazh...Exactly what I required...Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Pugazh....can you help with the following question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847685/if-else-in-javascript...its related to the same issue....

Answer (score -1):

**1)** Add a class e.g. `active` that does the same as your hover

```
.tab1:hover, .tab1.active {
  background: #3399CC;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

adding the class will highlight your element

**2)** The border color does not change at all, since you're removing the border with `border: none;` set another `border-color` or leave it as it is.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to down vote? I must have clicked something wrong. How can i correct this?